# Android in-app billing problem

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I tried out Google's example Dungeon application to buy an item i have uploaded the signed apk on my developer account. I downloaded it from the market and when i try to buy the sword item it says on the screen,

> sword_001: request purchase reeturned RESULT_ERROR

Which wasn't very descriptive.

Even though I had already put the item up on the application on my developer console, and it showed the billing screen and i clicked buy item but that error appeared.

On close inspection on the logcat i found this string. I still have no clue how to fix this

> 05-12 20:28:31.695: DEBUG/vending(1922): [102] BaseAction.run(): ApiException: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.PurchaseOrderRequest, Response=INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR

Comment: did you set item listing? actually android in-app billings sucks. they made is too difficult that we are wasting more time on integrating it rather then focusing on our logic. I am going to integrate PayPal it is much easier than this Fu**in s*it

Answer (score 1):

Your suppose to add the sword_001 as a product list in your market account

Answer (score 1):

please used this link https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/ this is very useful for you.and android-billing library is also good working.i implement this library in my project work well try it.